# Handle phisycal back button as a normal button

Tags: android, button, android-asynctask

Is it possible to handle the phisical back button as a normal button?

I don't want to handle its behaviour with the `onBackPressed()` method, but I want to handle it as a button, so a thing like:

```
Button backButton ....
backButton.setOnClickListener(...
```

I need this because I need to pass the back button as a parameter to an AsyncTask, that needs to check if it's pressed while the AsyncTask is on its`onPostExecute()` method.

Thanks guys.

Comment: And maybe you could add a boolean that will be set to true inside your onPostExecute so you know if you should proceed with regular onBackPressed(). So in your onBackPressed, first line would be if(postExecuteIndicator){...}

Comment: @NikolaMilutinovic For my needs, I prefer having this situation, handling the back button as a normal one.

Comment: Button is associated with View class. So I believe that your request is not possible to impelement that way. The same goes for all hardware buttons. Maybe something more complex with NDK can be acheieved but still sounds like a tricky thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a `Button` with `android:visibility="gone"` (visibility gone is option)
2. Write an `onClickListener()` on the created `Button`
3. In `onBackPressed()`, try `Button.performClick()`

Comment: Thanks mate, I didn't used `Button.perfomClick()` but I called a public method that does what I need.